# How to get the link of uploaded file using firebase in realtime?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage for uploading files. The code is:

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://fir-896a6.appspot.com");

final Uri selectedFile = data.getData();

StorageReference uploadRef = storageRef.child(selectedFile.getLastPathSegment());
UploadTask uploadTask = uploadRef.putFile(selectedFile);

uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                  Log.i("Success", "uploaded");
                }

}
```

It successfully uploads file. Now as the upload complete i want both links to that file (eg. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-896a6.appspot.com/o/17992?alt=media&token=68bd978a-4def-40d8-8edb-6526a15a94e3
and
gs://fir-896a6.appspot.com/17992) in realtime(maybe on onSuccessListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple code snippet from my blog:[Firebase Storage](http://engineering.letsnurture.com/firebase-storage/)

```
...
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", downloadUrl.toString());
                    showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Upload Complete", downloadUrl.toString(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            findViewById(R.id.button_step_3).setEnabled(false);
                            findViewById(R.id.button_step_4).setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });

                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(downloadUrl)
                            .into(mImageView);
                }
            })
...
```